# form_for structure for namespaced resource in index view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, html-table, rails-routing, form-for

I've tried to [follow the Rails docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#relying-on-record-identification) when constructing a `form_for` under a namespace.

The pecularity with my case is that I'm rendering one form for each object instance, all together in the `index` view (see code below).

**Why do I get the following error message:**

```
"undefined method `textfield' for #  < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder:0x00000103f04188>"
```

---

routes.rb:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :plans
end
```

controllers/admin/plans_controller.rb:

```
def index
  @plans = Plan.all
end
```

views/admin/plans/index.html.erb:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @plans.each do |plan| %>
      <tr>
        <%= form_for [:admin, plan] do |f| %>
        <td><%= f.textfield :title %></td>
        <td><%= f.submit "Save" %></td>
        <% end %>
      </tr> 
    <% end %>     
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Synatx issue it's `f.text_field`